# Post data from edittext to php script using httppost

Tags: php, android, post, android-asynctask

How do I pass user input (Edittext) to a php script on a server? I'm trying to get this working locally first through wamp. I have allowed all connections in the wamp conf file and created an alias to the folder I am using within my www folder. My code is as follows:

```
public class GetItemsActivity extends FoodSearchActivity {

public void postData(View v) {

    //get food from edit text box
    String food = txtFoodSearch.getText().toString();
    System.out.println(food);                               //see if user input is being picked up



    if(food.length()>0) {

    // Create a new HttpClient
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("000.000.000.00/SlimandSave/test.php");  //use address of local web server


     try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Food", "food"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        httpclient.execute(httppost);

        txtFoodSearch.setText(" "); //reset the message text field


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
} else {
    //display message if text field is empty
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All fields are     required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   

}
}
 }
```

for now I just want to be able to post the data over so my php is just going to output the search text to a text file;

```
    file_put_contents("myfile.txt", print_r( $_POST, true ));

?>
```

I have been looking at some questions on here and i'm now not sure whether I should be using asynctask, or if I am missing something obvious. Maybe it's the php? I appreciate any tips/advice.

Edit: i've just discovered that if I leave the edit text field blank the app still crashes when i click search so not sure where to look now

Further edit: I've also just discovered i never added the activity to the manifest for the button click, so the app is no longer hanging and crashing after the button click.

I am getting this from the logs now,

```
02-13 15:39:16.826: E/EditText(26019): bread
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to       instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.college.slimandsave/com.college.slimandsave.GetItemsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.college.slimandsave.GetItemsActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.college.slimandsave.GetItemsActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
02-13 15:39:16.876: E/AndroidRuntime(26019):    ... 11 more
```

FINALLY got this to work. In the code above I had to use txtFoodSearch.getText().toString() rather than just food, and I was just using the ip of my wamp server, I needed to add http:// to the ip address, thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Food", food));

Comment: nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Food", food)); For first test you can even use new Thread().

Comment: Thanks Guys I hadn't spotted that, but when I click search the app just hangs and then crashes still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whether I should be using `asynctask`, or if I am missing something obvious. Maybe it's the php?

Of course you should use it, as network operation are not allowed on `main Thread`.

> Maybe it's the php? I appreciate any tips/advice.

Here are my advices:

- **Read up** on [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

You would do something along the following lines:

```
 private class SearchFoodTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     protected void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      //here you execute the post request
      // You can call postData() here
     }

     protected void onPostExecute() {
       //onPostExecute is called when background task executed
       //this is the place to update the interface

       txtFoodSearch.setText(" ");
     }
 }
```

- **Debug**

Use logcat, log things to the screen or console, you have to know where there is an issue. Also dont just catch exeption , you have to use them print the stack trace to logcat otherwise it's pointless.

```
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

- **Server Side**

Keep things simple I like that you are writing to a file. I personaly like to use `error_log()` even though it might be for another purpose. You can improve the script by adding more checks:

```
 <?php
 // use file_put_contents, fwrite or error_log whichever you prefer

 //If this gets written to the log file it means
 //Android was able to reach
 error_log("script got called from");

 if(isset($_POST)){

    error_log("Post value is set".var_dump($_POST));

    if(isset($_POST['Food'])){
        error_log("Post food value is set".$_POST['Food']);
    }else{
        error_log("Post food value is not set");
    }

 }else{
    error_log("Post array not set");
 }

?>
```

If nothing gets logged then most likely the issue is the application.

If you follow these procedure you should never have to wonder `Maybe it's the php?` you will know exactly where the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for the help, one other thing my edittext field (txtFoodSearch) cannot be resolved when i extend AsyncTask, but if I extend FoodSearchActivity it can, but then i can't use AsyncTask. I have declared it a public so not sure why it can't be resolved.

Comment: maybe you can show me how you declared and initialized it. Lemme know we will sort it out. You can try to make it static since it is 2 different classes.

Comment: Thanks declaring it as a static did the trick, but as always when i solve one problem another appears.